# Rails 3 / SQL - A complex "exists?" query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

My models

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, :through => :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player
end
```

- Teams can have a different number of players
- Players can be on many teams
- Retrieving a team_id if it already exists **<- My problem**

When creating a new team, I'm basically choosing multiple players in a nested form. Upon create, I need to check if a team with the **exact** player composition already exist.

Example:

- Team 1: **A** (id 1) and **B** (id 2)
- Team 2: **A** (id 1), **B** (id 2) and **C** (id 3)

Lets say I create a new team with **A** and **B**, then I need the query somehow tell me if it exists or not, by returning the **team_id** or something, or an empty result.

I've played around with queries similar to this, but with no satisfying result

```
SELECT *, count(id) as c FROM "team_players" WHERE player_id IN (1,3) GROUP BY team_id HAVING c = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in two steps:

1. Find the teams that have all the players you're looking at.
2. Check if those teams have more players than the player set you're looking at.

That translates into this:

```
select team_id
from team_players
where team_id in (
    select team_id
    from team_players
    where player_id in (1,3)
    group by team_id
    having count(player_id) = 2
)
group by team_id
having count(player_id) = 2
```

Given this in `team_players`:

```
team_id|player_id
     1 | 1
     1 | 3
     1 | 4
     2 | 1
     2 | 3
     3 | 3
```

The above query says `team_id = 2` and there's your exact match. The query you're using gives you the teams that contain the players in question as a subset, not the teams that are set-wise equal to the players in question.

If you only want to know if such a team exists then wrap that query in a `select_rows` call and you're done:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    # players is an array of Fixnum player IDs
    def self.team_exist?(players)
        return false if(!players.present?)
        connection.select_rows(%Q{
            select team_id
            from team_players
            where team_id in (
                select team_id
                from team_players
                where player_id in (#{players.join(',')})
                group by team_id
                having count(player_id) = #{players.length}
            )
            group by team_id
            having count(player_id) = #{players.length}
        }).present?
    end
end
```

The `#{players.join(',')}` interpolation assumes that `team_exist?` is being given an array of Fixnum so you'll want to properly scrub your data in the caller or add a `players = players.map(&:to_i)` before the `connect.select_rows` call to scrub it inside `team_exist?`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using the connection.select_rows, because I want to grab the actual team_id value. But the query itself works just fine. (Except that you forgot to define the 'c' in the last having part)

Comment: @Frexuz: The `having c...` should have been `having count(player_id)...` right? I was translating between my made up nonsense names and your real names.